# How to fix music playback error for Discord bot?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am writing a bot for my own server. I decided to implement the command to play music by reference with a simple .play url command. I use the discord.py library, and for music youtube_dl. I found a way to do it, but the main library is already more improved and that method does not work at all, so errors occur. There are few errors left, two errors have already been decided. The bottom line is that discord.py does not seem to want to work with youtube_dl, either I don’t understand the essence of the error, or I'm just doing something wrong. I even had to import the VoiceClient function from discord.py.

**Error:**

```
Ignoring exception in command play:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Степан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 83, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:/Users/Степан/Desktop/Clown/main.py", line 57, in play
    player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url)
AttributeError: 'VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'create_ytdl_player'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Степан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 892, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\Степан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 797, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Степан\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 92, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'VoiceClient' object has no attribute 'create_ytdl_player'
```

**Code:**

```
import discord
import config
import random
import variables
import youtube_dl
from discord import utils
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.voice_client import VoiceClient

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')
players = {}


@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def play(ctx, url):
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
    await channel.connect()
    server = ctx.message.guild 
    voice_client = discord.utils.find(lambda c: c.guild.id == server.id, client.voice_clients)
    player = await voice_client.create_ytdl_player(url) # < Ошибка возникает тут
    players[server.id] = player
    player.start()
```

Comment: `create_ytdl_player` was removed in discord.py v1.0.0. It's no longer maintained and you shouldn't be using it.

Comment: @TinNguyen, Can you tell me what then you can use, well, or either how to downgrade the discord.py version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`create_ytdl_player` was removed in discord.py v1.0.0. It's no longer maintained and you shouldn't be using it.

> Can you tell me what then you can use, well, or either how to
>   downgrade the discord.py version?

I would heavily advise against downgrading the version since you'd be fighting with other issues which aren't fixed since the older version is outdated and not maintained.

Many major discord bots are using Lavalink: https://github.com/Frederikam/Lavalink

There are many different client libraries for Python as well. Do your research for which one you want to settle. Post any new questions coming from that in a new StackOverflow question. They also have a Discord server which is worth checkout out. See ReadMe from the GitHub I linked.

Comment: Good answer, I would also recommend providing a link to Lavalink.py so they can integrate it.

Comment: The ReadMe contains a list of lavalink clients including Lavalink.py but I don't want to promote a specific lavalink python client. The other ones are also in use and are maintained. The one I personally use(d) is also written in Python but isn't listed there.

Comment: Fair enough yeah!

Comment: @TinNguyen, Thank you very much for your help. Can you tell me lastly how to implement the connection?

`bot.lavalink.add_node ('127.0.0.1', 2333, 'youshallnotpass', 'eu', 'default-node')`

Need some special server? Or can I use a local network?

Comment: This error occurs: `NODE-eu-127.0.0.1: 2333] Failed to establish connection!`

Comment: or is it better to create a new question about this?